# Что делать с комментариями к вопросам и ответам при переводе с enSO?

Tags: обсуждение, перевод-содержимого

Встречаются очень забавные, на мой взгляд, комментарии, порою по объему превышающие ответ/вопрос. Надо-ли их переводить целиком или, как говорится действовать по месту. Отжимать всю воду, глупость и упорство спрашивающего, оставляя комментарии в урезанном количестве. Только те, которые позволяют понять, что человек в комментариях уточняет.

Приведу пример, который очень сокращен, заменены термины, но смысл и драйв остались те же. Q -вопрос; A - ответ

---

Q - мне необходимо проложить путь из точки А в точку Б. На моем пути встретилась преграда, в виде стенки, которую я не могу обойти. Пробовал перепрыгнуть не получилось. Сейчас пробую пробить стенку.

A - Не надо биться об стенку головой. В моем решении я предлагаю другой, более короткий путь.
Q - мне нужен именно **мой**  путь. Я надену каску и возьму более длинный разбег с горы.
A - пробуйте.        *Далее автор ответа замолкает*
Q - не получилось. Очень болит голова.
Q - вернусь на ферму и возьму мотоцикл
Q - не получилось, разбился шлем, голова и мотоцикл
Q - завтра, что нибудь ещё придумаю
Q - мне может кто нибудь помочь?

---

Было бы очень интересно услышать мнение сообщества, ну и поделитесь, пожалуйста  практическим опытом, как вы действуете в подобных случаях с комментариями.

Comment: Я лично ничего не понял. Причем тут enSO? Причем тут комментарии там? И зачем их куда-то переводить?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Я видел ранее вопросы к авторам перевода по ассоциации enSO. -- Почему нет перевода комментарий, почему комментарии приведены не в полном объеме?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Так как **вся необходимая информация должна быть в вопросе/ответе** - нет нужды переводить комментарии.

Если в них информация для вопроса - она должна быть добавлена в вопрос.

Если в них информация для ответа - она должна быть перенесена в ответ.

В обоих случаях необходимые данные должны быть встроены в существующий текст, а не просто приписаны сбоку, под плашкой/заголовком "комментарии".

Comment: В теории, по логике всё замечательно получается, а на практике вся логика тут же разрушится. Смотрите - вопрос и ответ разбиты на два отдельных поста. Как в верхний пост вопроса заносить комментарии, которые относятся к посту отвечающего?

Comment: @Alexandr_T, очень просто: сначала разносишь все по сторонам, у тебя получится вопрос и ответ, потом переводишь. Если ты имеешь ввиду диалог в комментарии - то тебе он не нужен. Выносишь _важную_ часть в соответствующую сторону  и все. В итоге, в большинстве случаев, от комментариев в исходном виде может ничего не остаться.

Comment: не буду спорить, надо опробовать на конкретных топиках.  Но выбрасывать всё, конечно не буду. В некоторых комментариях порою бывает более ценная информация, чем в ответе и вот ведь незадача, отвечающий и автор ценного коммента может быть третье лицо. Ничего, что я его авторства лишу?

Comment: @Alexandr_T, всегда можно упомянуть автора, всегда можно собрать информацию из комментариев и сделать _отдельный_ ответ. Но просто вставлять комментарии как есть - нет смысла. В крайнем случае можешь добавить их так же в комментарии :-)

Comment: Сделал новый перевод. Удалось запихнуть 4 комментария от других людей в авторский вопрос. Авторов комментов не стал указывать. Вроде нормально получилось. Это последние 4 абзаца через большие пробелы  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632539/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2/632540#632540

Comment: @Alexandr_T, вопрос не совсем удачный, похоже он был объединен с другим вопросом, поэтому в комментариях отвечает другой человек, да и сами комментарии написаны раньше чем задан вопрос :)

Comment: класс!!! А я даже не заметил, что комментарии апрель 14, а вопрос задан в сентябре 14 года. А так вроде всё гладко выглядит. Но не это важно, главное, что ответ оч. технически интересный и ценный на мой взгляд

Comment: действительно объединили топики  апрельские вопрос/ответы с сентябрьским вопросом/ответом `web-tiki`, а так как он был последним, то и расположен вверху.  Неаккуратно получилось у cклей-мастеров enSO. Если нужно, могу снести все комменты в переводном топике.

Answer (score 4):

Важно, нужно переводить:

1. Смысл.

Не важно, следует выкинуть:

1. Структуру распределения смысла по тексту: что было в ответе, а что в комментариях.
2. Личности, ум и характер спрашивающих и отвечающих.
3. Стилистические особенности текста.

Comment: я обоими руками за такой подход. Главное - четко смысл без лишних уточняющих подробностей. Ведь у них  на enSO это происходило в процессе выяснений, развития, а мы можем уже видеть финиш и выбрать самое ценное.  Нет ничего ценного, ну и нет комментарий у нас.

Comment: @Alexandr_T уточню: даже ценные комментарии незачем переводить как комментарии. Там информация разбросана по ответу и комментариям, потому что это был живой процесс. Но воспринимать это тяжело. Переводя, лучше выжать воду, а оставшийся смысл организовать в четкую структуру.